# AD user can't login to Centos 8

Tags: centos, active-directory, centos8

I have a new Centos 8 box. I also have Windows 2016-based domain controller that serves all my windows servers and workstations (about 10 altogether). I successfully joined AD - or at least it looks like it was successful. Cockpit shows correct domain, and I can do `kinit`:

```
# kinit adadmin
Password for adadmin@EXAMPLE.COM
#
```

(and if the password is wrong, I get `kinit: Password incorrect while getting initial credentials` as expected).

However, I cannot connect with as AD user. I also get the following errors:

```
# id adadmin
id: `adadmin': no such user
```

and

```
# net ads info
ads_connect: No logon servers are currently available to service the logon request.
Didn't find the ldap server!
```

Finally, I get the following error in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Nov 11 22:32:43 centos8 sssd[be[example.com]][12694]: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)
```

I tried different things in krb5.conf and sssd.conf - but it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was a new test machine, and nobody had any suggestions, I decided to trash this VM and start again. This time, rather than following "Join Domain" link on the cockpit page, I followed the [instructions](https://computingforgeeks.com/join-centos-rhel-system-to-active-directory-domain/) to "manually" join the domain. This worked perfectly fine.

So, I don't know if I did something wrong or there is a bug in the scripts that are underlying cockpit - but if anybody is reading this, and you had problems - try to join manually!